# Changing UITableView functionality on button press

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this - I have a `UITableView` of items which the user has previously selected and which is stored.  When you click an item it takes you to a detail page.  What I need is to be able to click a button below the table view which reloads the table and changes the accessory so its a tick instead of a disclosure, then the user can un-tick the items and remove them from the list, before clicking another button which reloads the updated table and restores the disclosure accessory.

Question is, what is the best way to "remember" which way to handle the table reload after the click so it knows which way to display it?  Would you use the `NSUserDefaults` to store a flag on the button click or is there a more elegant way to do it?  I guess I could use the status of the button, whether it's in one state or another, but I'm guessing there is something in-built I'm missing.

Hope that makes sense - thanks.

Comment: What about using a *static bool*? It will preserve it's value across method calls.

Comment: That's actually the kind of thing I was looking for - I need some way of preserving a flag to dictate which version of the table to show that will not be lost after a click event.  I guess I'm thinking in an ASP.net way again ;-)  I'll try that - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually I have some 'model object' and depending on array of those objects I construct table. My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    InterestsCell *cell = (InterestsCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kInterestsCellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        ...
    }

    Interest *i = (Interest*)[self.interestsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.myTfSubview.enabled = i.isChecked; 

    return cell;
}
```

If you don't have your model then you can create array of BOOL values and store flags there.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking at how to display the table but more to keep a flag set to determine which type of table to show.

Comment: @Dave, my thoughts on this - create some model object and store it in NSArray